# Chained Optional.map calls cause compilation error

Tags: java

I am trying out Java 8 `Optional` class:

```
static Optional<Integer> test() {
    return Optional.of(1).map(i -> Optional.of(i.toString()).map(j -> Integer.valueOf(j)));
}
```

In my thought, the function should return an Optional of Integer object 1. However Java 8 compiler is not happy:

```
Test.java:5: error: incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bounds
        return Optional.of(1).map(i -> Optional.of(i.toString()).map(j -> Integer.valueOf(j)));
                                 ^
    equality constraints: Integer
    lower bounds: Optional<U>
  where U,T are type-variables:
    U extends Object declared in method <U>map(Function<? super T,? extends U>)
    T extends Object declared in class Optional
```

Why is the compiler not happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [signature of `Optional`'s `.map()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) says that the `Function` given as an argument returns `U`, and not `Optional<U>`; this method will wrap `U` itself.

Therefore you have to:

```
Optional.of(1).map(i -> i.toString()).map(j -> Integer.parseInt(j))
```

(note: also, `Integer.valueOf()` was not what you meant; it does not take a `String` as an argument)

Finally, both your lambdas can be replaced with method references:

```
Optional.of(1).map(Object::toString).map(Integer::parseInt)
```